# Queue Path for MSMQ using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, msmq

I cannot seem to figure out how to format the queue path. I have never used MSMQ before. I set it up, create a private queue called test, and want to try sending a message.

I am using Visual Studio, ASP.NET, webforms, C#.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendPrivateTx();  
    }

    public void SendPrivateTx()
    {
        MessageQueue rmQ = new MessageQueue("jsmith528/private$/test");
        rmQ.Send("message", MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
    }
```

This is the code I'm using. I get an error on the line after the new MessageQueue that states:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Length cannot be less than zero.

I am sure this is the result of not having the correct path. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Try these: .\Private$\test or jsmith528\Private$\test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local private queue should be formatted as is:

```
@".\Private$\TextsQueue"
```

Here is an example of what my "StartQueue" looks like :

```
        List<ServiceController> services = ServiceController.GetServices().ToList();
        ServiceController msQue = services.Find(o => o.ServiceName == "MSMQ");
        if (msQue != null) 
        {
            if (msQue.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running) 
            { 
                // It is running.

                //Q Creation
                if (MessageQueue.Exists(@".\Private$\TextsQueue"))
                {

                    textsQueue = new System.Messaging.MessageQueue(@".\Private$\TextsQueue");

                }
                else
                    textsQueue = MessageQueue.Create(@".\Private$\TextsQueue");


                textsQueue.Purge();
                textsQueue.ReceiveCompleted += new
                ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(QueueReceiveCompleted);              
        }
```

Comment: Good. I needed to add double slashes. That was my error. "jsmith528\\private$\\test"